# Journey Logging for more than one entrance

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I want to log the step the person is at a given moment in the journey in Journey Builder with the use of the solution using Update Contact Activity. I've created a logging DE that includes the fields of SubKey, Journey Name, ActivityNumber, DateActivityReached.

I'm modifying the steps described here: https://sprignaturemoves.com/journey-logging-using-update-contact/) but I'm not using the second DE and the automation as the journey logging will be done for only one journey.

The logging DE in my case will have a retention period of one month but there's a possibility that someone enters the journey the second time BEFORE they hit the retention period and are removed from the journey.

Is it even possible to log the same person (SubcriberKey) twice in the logging DE when this person is at two different stages of the journey? If I remove the Primary Key from the SubKey would this solution still make sense?

Thank you for any input in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Adam's article was to demonstrate an approach to working around the limitations of an Update Contact activity. These activities perform an upsert based on the Contact Key/Subscriber Key. Changing your primary key on your logging table won't alter the behaviour. You will simply end up with a single row for each contact that's overwritten with each instance of the Contact in the Journey.

Removing the secondary Data Extension and Automation from Adam's solution misses the point. They're integral to the solution and it's a solution that provides a workaround for your precise problem, irrespective of whether you're logging for fifty Journeys or just the one. If you do not want to log for other Journeys, you can drop the "Journey" field in both tables, but the tables and Automation remain.

One addition I'd recommend adding to what Adam has laid out is, if you can, generate a unique identifier for each entry event. It adds considerable complexity and you will need to get conversant with [Data Binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) syntax, but it allows you to differentiate between instances of the same contact in your Journey for Decision Splits and/or reporting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it makes more sense for me now. I guess this solution could work for my case but I wonder if I could add the second DE to the Data Model - the one that's created through the automation to use in other journeys decision splits?

Comment: You could definitely add your logging DE to the Data Model to use in decision splits. Keep in mind that, by default, decisions are based on the contact and not the particular instance of the contact in the journey. You're likely going to need to use data binding where you also log the unique identifier for the record in the Journey to your logging DE. This might be the SalesOrderNumber (or similar) that's a natural primary key or might be an artificial primary key that you generate when injecting into the Journey. The you need to match attributes from the Journey Data to the Contact Model.