# Logging Journey Step information in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data-views

I wonder if there is any way in Marketing Cloud to log the information about a specific step a subscriber is at in a given journey with the use of Data Views? Not only emails but also any other activities added to the Journey canvas.

I see that in a DataView called _JourneyActivity there is a field called ActivityType but I don't really have an idea on how to use it in a query.

Is there any other way to somehow store this information without the use of Update Contact Activity after each step in a Journey?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found much meaningful info from the journey data views. You'll have to leverage Update Contact steps for Journey logging and build the logging/reporting yourself.

Example [here](https://sprignaturemoves.com/journey-logging-using-update-contact/).

The gist is:

1. Create a status DE and relate it to the Contact in Contact Builder
2. Create a log DE to receive the status rows
3. Create a Query Activity in an hourly Automation that sweeps status rows to the log
4. Use the Update Contact activity in your Journey to record whatever you need

All your Journeys can use the same status and log DE.

**Edit**:

I see you're [familiar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343422/journey-logging-for-more-than-one-entrance) with the process I've outlined on my blog.  Perhaps you can elaborate on the challenges you have implementing it.

Comment: Hello Adam, thank you for the link. Yes, I have already set up this solution and it is working fine. The problem is that the journey is going to grow substantially soon with many new activities and adding Update Contact Activity would make it much more complicated to handle. I wanted to find a solution that would do everything in Automation Studio (like querying Data Views) to improve the performance of the journeys.